# how to calculate the marginal distribution of probabilistic principal component analysis

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, machine-learning, pattern-recognition

In the book Pattern recognition and machine learning from Bishop equation 12.33 states:

$\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{W} \mathbf{z} + \boldsymbol\mu + \boldsymbol\epsilon$

Here $\mathbf{z}$ has a normal distribution $N(\mathbf{z} | \mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I})$ and $\boldsymbol\epsilon$ has a normal distribution $N(\boldsymbol\epsilon | \mathbf{0}, \sigma² \mathbf{I})$

Thus, the conditional probability $p(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{z})$ is equal to

$p(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{z}) = N(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{W}\mathbf{z} + \boldsymbol \mu, \sigma^2 \mathbf{I})$

The marginal distribution $p(\mathbf{x})$ can then be computed with

$p(\mathbf{x}) = \int p(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{z}) p(\mathbf{z}) d\mathbf{z}$

and according to the book this is equal to $N(\mathbf{x}| \boldsymbol\mu, \mathbf{C})$ with $\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{W} \mathbf{W}^T + \sigma^2 \mathbf{I}$. How did the author calculated the integral to come to this result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean and variance of the marginal density can be directly evaluated from the expression $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{Wz}+\boldsymbol{\mu}+\boldsymbol{\epsilon}$.

Nevertheless, the more lengthy approach of evaluating the integral is a useful exercise in how to deal with integrals of exponential functions whose argument is a quadratic function of vectors, as is the case with the multivariate Normal distribution.

The objective is to calculate the integral
$$\begin{align}p(\mathbf{x})=&\int \color{blue}{p(\mathbf{x}|\mathbf{z})}\color{red}{p(\mathbf{z})}d\mathbf{z}\\=&\int\color{blue}{\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}\sigma^n}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{Wz}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^T(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{Wz}-\boldsymbol{\mu})\right)}\color{red}{\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{z}^T\mathbf{z}\right)}d\mathbf{z}\end{align}$$
Expanding the arguments of the exponential functions, and after some rearrangement we end up with 
$$p(\mathbf{x})=\int\frac{1}{(2\pi)^n\sigma^n}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{z}^T\left[\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{W}+\mathbf{I}\right]\mathbf{z}-\frac{2}{\sigma^2}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^T\mathbf{Wz}-\frac{2}{\sigma^2}\boldsymbol{\mu}^T\mathbf{x}\\+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\boldsymbol{\mu}^T\boldsymbol{\mu}\right)d\mathbf{z} \text{ Eq.(1)}$$
To aid in integration with respect to $\mathbf{z}$, we can conceptually regard the integrand as a Normal density in terms of random variable $\mathbf{z}$, with mean $\boldsymbol{\mu_z}$ and variance matrix $\mathbf{C_z}$, where the argument of the exponential function would be
$$\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{z}-\boldsymbol{\mu_z})^T\mathbf{C_z}^{-1}(\mathbf{z}-\boldsymbol{\mu_z})\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{z}^T\mathbf{C_z}^{-1}\mathbf{z}-2\boldsymbol{\mu_z}^T\mathbf{C_z}^{-1}\mathbf{z}+\color{red}{\boldsymbol{\mu_z}^T\mathbf{C_z}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu_z}})\right)$$ 
Comparing the above expression with the integrand (Eq.($1$)), except for the term highlighted in red (*which we will add and subtract from the integrand, similar to the method of completing the square*), we can match the mean and variance to the appropriate terms in the integrand
$$\begin{align} \mathbf{C_z}^{-1}&=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{W}+\mathbf{I}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{W}+\sigma^2\mathbf{I})\\ \boldsymbol{\mu_z}^T\mathbf{C_z}^{-1}&=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^T\mathbf{W}\\\Rightarrow \color{red}{\boldsymbol{\mu_z}^T\mathbf{C_z}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu_z}}&=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^T\mathbf{W}(\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{W}+\sigma^2\mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{W}^T(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})\end{align}$$
Thus we have the following (where the $\mathbf{z}$ term is a Normal density, and so integrates to unity)
$$p(\mathbf{x})\propto\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(-\color{red}{\boldsymbol{\mu_z}^T\mathbf{C_z}^{-1}\boldsymbol{\mu_z}}-\frac{2}{\sigma^2}\boldsymbol{\mu}^T\mathbf{x}+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\boldsymbol{\mu}^T\boldsymbol{\mu})\right)\int\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{z}|\boldsymbol{\mu_z},\mathbf{C_z})d\mathbf{z}\\=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^T\mathbf{W}(\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{W}+\sigma^2\mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{W}^T(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})-\frac{2}{\sigma^2}\boldsymbol{\mu}^T\mathbf{x}+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{x}+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\boldsymbol{\mu}^T\boldsymbol{\mu})\right)\\=\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^T\mathbf{C_x}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})\right)$$
which is in the form of a Normal distribution with respect to $\mathbf{x}$, where the mean is simply $\boldsymbol{\mu}$.

It remains to evaluate the variance matrix of $\mathbf{x}$, $\mathbf{C_x}$ where
$$\mathbf{C_x}^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{W}(\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{W}+\sigma^2\mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{W}^T)$$
We use the [Woodbury matrix identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity), restated as follows (for matrices $\mathbf{A}$, $\mathbf{U}$, $\mathbf{C}$ and $\mathbf{V}$)
$$\mathbf{(A + UCV)^{-1}=A^{-1}-U(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U)VA^{-1}}$$
and setting $\mathbf{A}=\sigma^2\mathbf{I}$, $\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{I}$, $\mathbf{U=W}$ and $\mathbf{V=W}^T$ leads to
$$(\sigma^2\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}^T)^{-1}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{I}-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{I}(\mathbf{W}(\mathbf{I}+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{W}))^{-1}\mathbf{W}^T)\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{I}\\=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{W}(\mathbf{W}^T\mathbf{W}+\sigma^2\mathbf{I})^{-1}\mathbf{W}^T)\\=\mathbf{C_x}^{-1}$$
resulting in
$$\mathbf{C_x}=\sigma^2\mathbf{I}+\mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}^T=\mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}^T+\sigma^2\mathbf{I}$$
which is what we set out to show.

Summarising, the marginal density $p(\mathbf{x})$ is Normal with mean $\boldsymbol{\mu}$ and variance matrix $\mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}^T+\sigma^2\mathbf{I}$.